# EF 6 - Error Exception calling SetData with 2 argument(s)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a solution with multiple projects. The DBContext file and Models are in a ClassLibrary project. This project has EF 6.1.3 and it is running on .NET 4.5.2. The models and DBContext files are in different file structure, I mean Models are in Project/Data/Model and DBContext is in Data folder. This project appears to have migration enabled to an existing database. The development team used to just recreate database by building the project. It also has:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
```

I am trying to use migration properly and have tried following to see it PackageManagerConsole react properly.

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

Both resulted in following error:

```
Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly  'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable." At C:\Users\Temp\.nuget\packages\EntityFramework\6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:718 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('project', $project)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException   Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly  'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable." At C:\Users\Temp\.nuget\packages\EntityFramework\6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:719 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('contextProject', $contextProject)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException   Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in assembly  'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable." At C:\Users\Temp\.nuget\packages\EntityFramework\6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720 char:5
+     $domain.SetData('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project, String propertyName)    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String contextTypeName)    at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0() at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Could you please review and let me know what is causing the error. I have also tried setting the Startup project to other projects in the solution.

Comment: Hi @alijohn , were you able to make it work? If your are still experiencing this problem, maybe this other question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/38437958/967736

Comment: May be this solution help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308170/enable-migrations-installation-error/17366699#17366699

Answer (score 0):

Good Evening,

I believe I've found your error. Based on the provided information, it revolves around the serialization of specific types during the Entity Framework migration. The error message indicates that a type (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject) is not marked as serializable, and this is causing a problem during the migration process.

In order to fix this, I would recommend:

1. Check Compatibility to verify that the version of Entity Framework you are using is compatible with the version of Visual Studio you have. Sometimes, certain versions of EF might have issues with specific versions of Visual Studio.

and

2. Explicitly Set ContextAssemblyName in Configuration. In your Configuration.cs file (created during the migration setup), you can try explicitly setting the ContextAssemblyName. Open the Configuration.cs file inside the Migrations folder and add the following line inside the Configuration class constructor:
   ContextAssemblyName = "YourNameHere";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).