# EF6 Enable-Migrations not working in ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created an **ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)** project in VS2017. Then using NuGet I installed the **EntityFramework 6.1.3** (I cannot use *EF Core* because it does not support `DbGeometry` and `DbGeography`) .

Now when trying to to run the `Enable-Migrations` command in *Package Manager Console* it throws null reference exception.

> Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): .....
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

There is only one project in my solution and is set in the Default project part of the Package Manager Console. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436256/enable-migrations-exception-calling-setdata-with-2-arguments) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308170/enable-migrations-installation-error) but non of them work in my case. Also there is not `project.json` file in my solution, it seems some of these answer are out of date.

Here is the snapshot of the exception message

[image]

**EDIT:** I have these packages

[image]

Comment: And when you just run your first add-migration?   I seem to remember that enable wasn't always needed anymore.

Comment: @HenkHolterman same error occurs when running first add-migration (without enabling it)

Comment: Well, "it works on my machine" ....   You probably have some missing/outdated/conflicting  package somewhere. Take a good look at the errors/output from restore-packages and rebuild-all.

Comment: I have much more pkgs. But what might matter more, my context and model classes are not in ASP.NET Core but in Fx 4.6 projects.

Comment: You may need to move the EF6 to a separate project that targets .Net 4.x as described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/1830)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't solve it in Core. instead, I created a standard .net class library for the code-first project and referenced it in the Core project. So I did the code-first related jobs with that standard project and used them in the Core project.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the command `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration [your_migration_name]`. There was no need for `enable-migrations`. If I was to try .NET framework standard `add-migration [migration_name]`, the following warning would pop up:

```
Both Entity Framework 6.x and Entity Framework Core commands are installed. 
The Entity Framework 6 version is executing. You can fully qualify the command to select which one to execute, 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for EF6.x and 'EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration' for EF Core.'
```

Followed by the same exception you pasted above.